# Number of subgraphs with matching of size $n$ for a complete bipartite graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory, bipartite-graphs

Say we have a $K_{n,n}$ bipartite graph (i.e. a complete bipartite graph with $n$ nodes on each side). We induce a subgraph by deleting some subset of edges. There are $2^{n^2}$ possible subgraphs. How many of these subgraphs still contain a matching of size $n$. Is there a known non-trivial upper bound?

Furthermore, how can you compute the number of subgraphs which contain a matching of at least size $x$ for $x\leq n$?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the number of such subgraphs is known only up to $n=7$.  See [OEIS A227414](https://oeis.org/A227414) and Example 10.4 in [Permutohedra, Associahedra, and Beyond](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507163), by Alexander Postnikov.

Comment: $n=8$ would be a fairly easy calculation.  One day...

Answer (score 0):

If a bound down to a factor of $1+o(1)$ will do: Almost all bipartite graphs $G$ with one side $X$ and the other side $Y$ still have a perfect matching.

Here is a sketch of the proof: Form a subgraph $G$ of $K_{n,n}$ as follows: For each edge $e$ in $K_{n,n}$, flip a fair coin as to whether to keep $e$ in $G$ or not. Then every subgraph of $K_{n,n}$ has the same probability of resulting from this. However, one can show via a counting argument that with high probability, $G$ is such that every set $S$ in one side has at least $|S|$ neighbours on the other side. [Indeed, check out proofs that say that random bipartite $k$-regular graphs for $k \ge 3$ are expanders, similar principle at work here.]